# How to assign multiple Tickets to user?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to duplicate a simple ticketing system. I've got the database all set up with SQLite3 and php. So far so good. I'm not so good with databases, so here is my question:

A user buys 3 tickets from one account, each ticket having a unique TicketID. How does one go about assigning 3 tickets to a single user?

Here is a solution i thought of:

User Database -> username(primary key)

Ticket Database -> Adding ticket referenced by username.

Comment: add a field to ticket `owner` which points(references) to customer table.

Comment: @Riqwan What do you think is wrong with your solution? Resp., why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Any specific reason you're using SQLite over MySQL?

Comment: Ah, it worked. I made a semantic error on the column names, thats why it wasn't working. Hence the question.

@Prix. this is just a simple project. SQLite is easier to set up and get things going than MYSql. Mostly because its a new experience. :)